# 9 patch shows nothing on open

Tags: android, nine-patch

I am learning `9 patch` in Android but when I open I am just getting below image.

[image]

Now I am confused on how to start the 9 patch as nothing is present here to start.

Comment: You must open an existing file (this is **not a DRAWING** program). Also drag 'n' drop works fine.

Comment: @DerGolem thanks for your response....now I am trying for button this means I need to have an existing button image? if yes how to create a button image? Sorry for my immature question but first time I have learnt there is something like `9 patch`

Comment: Yes, exactly. To create a button image... use Google/Images/select some you like? or make some in Paint/Gimp/PhotoShop? or take them from the android SDK? The answer is broad...

Comment: @DerGolem no problem I will start by creating one... thanks for your guidance

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it was helpful, somehow. The rest of the process is trivial: add a 1px border on each side, add the black pixels, save the file as my_file.9.png - drag'n'drop it into the tool to adjust it

Comment: @DerGolem I can accept it as answer.. if you post your response as answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must open an existing file (this is not a DRAWING program).

To create a button image. either:

- use Google/Images/select some you like
- make some in Paint/Gimp/PhotoShop
- or take them from the android SDK

The choice is broad.

The rest of the process is trivial:

- add a 1px border on each side of your picture
- add the black pixels (up and left side to set the **stretchable** area/s, right and bottom sides to set the **padding** - mostly used for keeping the text evenly spaced from the boundaries)
- save the file as my_file.9.png (**.9.png**!)
- drag'n'drop it into the tool to adjust it